# Vapor 3: Create Custom Server Response

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I want to create a custom server response for my controllers and my errors.

Here is the model:

```swift
struct ServerResponse<T: Content>: Content {
    let code: Int
    let message: String
    let data: T?
}
```

My create request:

```swift
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<ServerResponse<User>> {
        try req.content.decode(User.self).flatMap { user in
            user.save(on: req).map { user in
                ServerResponse(code: ?, message: ?, data: user)
            }
        }
    }
```

In case of success, how can I get the `HTTPStatus` code to add it to the Response?

And the message if success is `OK`, if the error is a custom description or the description of the `HTTPStatus`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Content` protocol conforms to a `ResponseCodable` protocol that in turn conforms to a `ResponseEncodable` protocol. Vapor uses the `ResponseEncodable` protocol to convert a type to an `EventLoopFuture<Response>` that it can send to the client.

What you'll want to do is define a custom implementation of the `encode(for:)` method that `ResponseEncodable` requires. It will look something like this:

```swift
func encode(for request: Request) -> Future<Response> {
    do {
        let response = Response(status: HTTPResponseStatus(statusCode: self.code))
        try response.content.encode(self.data)
        return request.eventLoop.future(response)
    } catch let error {
        return request.eventLoop.future(error: error)
    }
}
```

I don't really know how you plan on using the `message` property, so I left that out.

As a side note, you probably only need to conform your custom type to `ResponseEncodable` instead of `Content`, but it won't make a big difference.

Comment: I use message because if there is a server error I want to get the description of the error or custom error. `tryFuture` not member of `eventLoop`, I cant try your implemention

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen Yeah, I just noticed you're on Vapor 3, not 4. Let me edit my answer to account for that.